# An interesting,scary and an old riddle

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, situation, mystery

One night I was visiting a friend of mine . I didn't visit him for a long time , though he was a very old friend . We had the following conversation :-

> Friend :- I am very happy to see you my friend !!

> Me :- Yeah , it's good to see you again !!

> Friend :- Will you stay in my home tonight ? You can sleep in the spare bed this night .

> Me :- Yeah sure, it's better to stay a night than walking home .

> Friend :- Kill some time here then , for I like having company . It's too lonely alone .

> Me :- Yes I can understand . Living alone can be tough .

> Friend :- You look very tired . You should just get some rest right now .

> Me :- Yes I am a bit tired today , had a lot of work .

> Friend :- While you're sleeping , make sure the windows are closed . There are so many bugs in the neighbourhood . Goodnight Then !!

> Me :- Ok sure , goodnight !!

After closing the windows, I went to sleep in his spare bed . However, after thinking about the conversation I suspected a big problem and immediately left his house and ran away from the door .

What made me do so?

First to answer this will be marked as the accepted answer :)

Comment: I thought perhaps the unusual-for-English spacing around the punctuation might have something to do with the riddle ….

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Presumably you noticed that

> The first word if each of his first four replies form the sentence "I will kill you".
>  If you join it with the first phrase of the fifth reply, you get "I will kill you while you're sleeping.".

Comment: Correct , it was an old riddle though .